# Can a stored procedure work with two different databases? How about two servers?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I am wondering if MySQL's stored procedures can work with two different databases on the same machine? How about if they are on different servers?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If we're talking about two databases on the same server: yes, a stored procedure can access another database. You have to make sure that the user under whose privileges the procedure is being run has the necessary privileges on each database.

For example, suppose you have two databases on the same server, `mydb1` and `mydb2`, and that each contains a table named `messages` with the same structure. Suppose you want to add a stored procedure to `mydb2` that empties the `messages` table in `mydb2` and copies the contents of the `messages` table in `mydb1`. You could do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SynchroniseMessages` ()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN

DELETE FROM `mydb2`.`messages`;

INSERT INTO
    `mydb2`.`messages`
    SELECT * FROM `mydb1`.`messages`;

END
```

See how I've fully qualified the tables with the databases to which they belong. In fact you could argue that I'm being over-zealous here, because we specified that this stored procedure will belong in `mydb2`. I don't need to add the `mydb2.` qualifier. If the stored procedure were in the `mydb1` database, I would need those qualifiers, but conversely I wouldn't need the `mydb1.` where it appears.

In order to be able to run this procedure (possibly in order to be able to define it?), I'd need to make sure my user has `DELETE` and `INSERT` privileges on `mydb2`, and also `SELECT` privileges on `mydb1`.

Databases on different servers sounds rather more complicated.

Comment: what if I want user **a** to be able to call a procedure that manipulates database **b** but I don't want user **a** to have those permissions on database **b**... for example a controled delete: I wouldn't allow user **a** to execute arbitrary delete statements on database **b**, but maybe I do want him to be able to delete certain information determined inside the stored procedure, like a cache.

Comment: @santiago arizti, as I understand it, the behaviour you describe is already conferred by the `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Also use Different Databases on different servers but you need to link them and use a same account (for example an active directory account) for both of them to connect

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it can work with 2 databases on one server, but only if they have the same login details It is not possible on 2 different servers.

The stored procedure is executed under one database connection. All the databases that the connection's login has access to, are available in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the databasename.tablename notation. Remote databases - I don't know of such a way in MySQL.. It's possible in MS SQL Server.