# Making stored procedures not unique to a particular database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

Okay, I have a theoretical database server that has several databases that contain the same schemas, but different data that can't be consolidated. Would it be possible to create procedures on the server that are database agnostic so that someone can run the procedure and input the database name and other parameters and the procedure calls the proper database.

Similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCatsForPerson (VARCHAR database, VARCHAR personName)
BEGIN
USE database;
select cats.catName, cats.ownerName from cats
where cats.ownerName = personName;
END
```

Or should I simply just create the procedure in each database?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014780/can-a-stored-procedure-work-with-two-different-databases-how-about-two-servers

Comment: I think you would have to do this either with a bunch of `if` statements and repeated code or with prepare statements that put each SQL statement into a string, where you can specify whichever database you want.